# How to automatically set DataSourceUpdateMode in the designer?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a custom control with a two-way bindable property. I also raise a `ValueChanged` event on the value's setter.

For this type of custom control I need to change the [DataSourceUpdateMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datasourceupdatemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `OnPropertyChanged` instead of the standard `OnValidating`.

As I'm doing all the data-binding within the designer, is it possible that the custom control set's the databinding to `OnPropertyChanged` once its added to the form?

EDIT:

Currently I'm doing this:

```
    protected override void OnCreateControl()
    {
        base.OnCreateControl();

        Binding binding = this.DataBindings[0] as Binding;
        if (binding != null)
        {
            binding.DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;
        }
    }
```

Is this the correct way or is the `OnBindingContextChanged` a more suitable event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnCreateControl` is useless and `OnBindingContextChanged` is more suitable place to change `DataBindings`. Also instead of `DataBindings[0]` you should use a loop over `DataBindings` and if you want to apply the logic on a specific property, use an `if` statement to check `PropertyName` of `Binding` object:

```
protected override void OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Binding item in DataBindings)
    {
        if (item.PropertyName == "SomeProperty")
            item.DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;
    }
    base.OnBindingContextChanged(e);
}
```

As an idea to apply such custom initialization tasks you can implement [`ISupportInitialize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize(v=vs.110).aspx) interface and put the logic which you want to apply when initialization completes in `EndInit`  method.